# Should questions that are unanswerable until later (unaired) episodes/chapters be allowed?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

Should we allow questions of the type:

1. Currently airing show or manga.
2. The question is unanswerable as of all the released episodes/chapters.
3. The question is likely to be revealed later on.

Because these questions are temporarily unanswerable, they may be considered "not constructive" as they can only be answered with speculation.

Examples:

- [What are the feathers on Rei's neck?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/what-are-the-feathers-on-reis-neck)
- [What does Unohana Retsu's Bankai do?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/what-does-unohana-retsus-bankai-do)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

As per [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/questions-on-ongoing-series-5-chat-cast).

However, the answers need to be of the form:

- If the answer is incomplete, it needs to say, "As of episode X, all we know is Y."
- If the answer is speculative, it needs to say, "As of episode X, we know, Y and Z. Therefore it is possible that..."

When the answer is finally revealed, the real answers will come without invalidating the existing answers. Furthermore, the existing answers will still be useful to people picking up the series late and don't want a full spoiler. (So we should probably hide the real answers in spoiler blocks.)

---

While there's a window of time where such questions are not answerable/constructive, it still has value for the following reasons:

- They will become answerable later on - thus making them legit questions.
- People searching for the question will know that the answer isn't revealed yet.
- It helps draw in search engine traffic from fansub watchers who watch currently airing shows.

---

The first point is pretty self-explanatory. If they will be good questions later on, there's no point in closing/deleting just to be reopen/re-ask/undelete later on.

For the second point, consider this (very common) situation:

You're watching a show and at some point, a question pops up and you go, "Whhhaaaat?!?! Did I miss something?" What are you going to do next? You search online...

You come across the same question on Anime.SE and you see that it has no answers or has several speculative answers of the form, "as of episode X". Now you know that you *didn't* miss anything and that the answer is not known yet.

Voila! The question is already useful.

And finally the last point is pretty self-explanatory. The scenario above will likely be the typical case in drawing in traffic.